# Would an object falling on the surface of the Sun look like this?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, simulations, sun, software

I've been playing around with some rustic animation and then I came to simulating gravity over squishy objects, I simulated a squishy ball of unknown "squishiness" (I'm sorry I don't know a lot of things related to physics, or the world in general :P), and on earth the escape velocity is `~9.81m/2²` so I tried to create something that would simulate an object falling on earth (with no air resistance), from a height of `4.9M`, it took a nice(roughly) 0.5s to hit the ground (I added some bouncing), then I searched for the sun's escape velocity and I found that it was 171ms(probably wrong), but when I did the simple math `4.9m/171m/s² = 0.02s`, so the animation looked something like what I made below using jQuery.

My question is, would an object falling on the sun look like on my animation (ignoring the fact of the extreme heat and other stuff)?

See the animation [here](http://liveweave.com/uGtoL8)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
    <style>
      #box{
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% - 100px);
        left: calc(50% - 100px);
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
      }
      #obj{
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% - 100px);
        left: calc(50% - 10px);
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 100%;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="box">
      <div id="obj"></div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="dropTheBallOnTheEarth();">Earth</button>
    <button onclick="dropTheBallOnTheSun();">Sun</button>
    <button onclick="Reset();" style="position:absolute; bottom:10px;left:10px;">RESET</button>
    <span style="position:absolute; bottom:50px;left:10px;">Earth's escape velocity is approximally 9.8ms, Thus 4.9m/9.8 = 0.5s</span>
    <span style="position:absolute; bottom:30px;left:10px;">Earth's escape velocity is approximally 171ms, Thus 4.9m/171ms = 0.02s</span>
  </body>
  <script>
    var b = $('#obj');

    function Reset(){
      $(b).animate({top:"0px",left:'90px', height:'20px'},500);
    }


    function dropTheBallOnTheEarth(){
      //top
      $(b).animate({ top: "+=1"}, 50);
          $(b).animate({ top: "+=3"}, 50);
      $(b).animate({ top: "+=6"}, 50);
          $(b).animate({ top: "+=10"}, 50);
      $(b).animate({ top: "+=15"}, 50);
          $(b).animate({ top: "+=21"}, 50);
      $(b).animate({ top: "+=28"}, 50);
          $(b).animate({ top: "+=36"}, 50);
      $(b).animate({ top: "+=45"}, 50);
          $(b).animate({ top: "+=13"}, 10);

      $(b).animate({ top: "+=6", height:'14px'}, 10);
          //bottom
          $(b).animate({ top: "-=21", height:'20px'}, 10);

      $(b).animate({ top: "-=15"}, 50);
          $(b).animate({ top: "-=10"}, 50);
      $(b).animate({ top: "-=6"}, 50);
          $(b).animate({ top: "-=3"}, 50);

      $(b).animate({ top: "-=1"}, 50);
          //top
          $(b).animate({ top: "+=1"}, 50);

      $(b).animate({ top: "+=3"}, 50);
          $(b).animate({ top: "+=6"}, 50);
      $(b).animate({ top: "+=10"}, 50);
          $(b).animate({ top: "+=15"}, 50);

      $(b).animate({ top: "+=18", height:'18px'}, 50);
          //bottom
          $(b).animate({ top: "-=10", height:'20px'}, 40);

      $(b).animate({ top: "-=6"}, 50);
          $(b).animate({ top: "-=3"}, 50);

      $(b).animate({ top: "-=1"}, 50);
          //top
          $(b).animate({ top: "+=1"}, 50);
      $(b).animate({ top: "+=3"}, 50);
          $(b).animate({ top: "+=6"}, 50);

      $(b).animate({ top: "+=9",height:'18px'}, 50);
          //bottom
          $(b).animate({ top: "-=3",height:'20px'}, 50);

      $(b).animate({ top: "-=1"}, 50);
          //top
          $(b).animate({ top: "+=1"}, 50);

      $(b).animate({ top: "+=3",height:'19px'}, 50);

      setTimeout(Reset(), 10000);
    }

    //171ms
    function dropTheBallOnTheSun(){
      var b = $('#obj');
          //top
          $(b).animate({ top: "+=199",height:'0'}, 20);
      setTimeout(Reset(), 10000);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: This is my first question on Physics, so if it needs to be improved tell me :D

Comment: I think you dont understand the difference between scape peed and the acceleration of gravity. Btw, if the height is very big you have to consider the variation of gravity with altitude.

Comment: ... also ignoring the fact that the sun has no solid surface to impact upon...

Comment: @Daniel Griscom sure, let's pretend it's got a flat surface, the point I tried to emulate was gravity acting upon an object and normal force, how would I see the changes on the object otherwise? Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @jinawee sure, I would have to square the gravity force upon the object based on the distance, but I don't think that 4.9 meters from the sun's surface would weakens its gravitational force. Thanks for your comment

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains no discernible physics. Other members can also not be expected to read code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your video is appropriate, the sun is in place and all the rest, including the fascinating scenery. Remember, if you're thinking of adding anything else, do not move the object hitting the sun, whatsoever. The sun's gravity is unimaginably powerful, so making bouncing effects would seem unrealistic. Also, as the sun has strong heat, (I know you mentioned something about this) but if it's possible for you to make the object go through a wave-like motion from the fiery rays, the animation would be almost perfect. What you did so far is good from my perspective but lacks the 'real world' part. Keep up the good work and I hope my answer helped!

Comment: It certainly did, I was really interested to see how fast would the ball go, and the normal force once  it hits the suns (imaginary solid) surface.

Comment: This is not an answer. It's a 'well done!' note that contains almost no physics.

Comment: The sun's gravity can certainly be imagined, and calculated as well. 'Skipping' across the surface could certainly be imagined (for something made of unobtanium).